# cant figure out how to always subtract smaller num from larger

Tags: c++, cmath

i have the whole program except for the part where it always subtracts the smaller number from the larger number. I've been trying to find it but i couldn't find anything to help me with it. that's the only part i need help with.

Here is the code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

//function prototype
int getRandomNumber(int lower, int upper);

int main()
{
//declare variables
int smallest = 0;
int largest = 0;
int num1 = 0;
int num2 = 0;
int correctAnswer = 0;
int userAnswer = 0;

//initialize rand function
srand(static_cast<int>(time(0)));

cout << "Smallest Integer: ";
cin >> smallest;
cout << "Largest Integer: ";
cin >> largest;
cout << endl;

for (int x = 1; x < 6; x += 1)
{
//generate two random integers
//from smallest through largest, then
//calculate the sum
num1 = getRandomNumber(smallest, largest);
num2 = getRandomNumber(smallest, largest);
correctAnswer = num1 - num2;

//display addition problem and get user's answer
cout << "what is the difference of " << num1 <<" - " << num2 << " ? ";
cin >> userAnswer;

//determine wether user's answer is correct
if (userAnswer == correctAnswer)
cout << "Correct";
else
cout << " Sorry, the correct answer is " << correctAnswer << ".";
//end if
cout << endl << endl;
} //end for

return 0;
} //end of main function

//*****function definitions*****
int getRandomNumber(int lower, int upper)
{
int randInteger = 0;
//generate random integer from lower through upper
randInteger = lower + rand() % (upper - lower + 1);
return randInteger;
} //end of getRandomNumber function

need help!
```

Comment: There's a function in `<cmath>` that might help you eliminate checking which is smaller altogether.

Comment: Does it always subtract the smaller from the larger and you do not want it to? Or do you want it to always subtract smaller from larger, but it does not? But the way you phrase the question in the output I think the program should do exactly as it does. What am I missing?  I would answer 5 to "what is the difference of 17 - 12 ?" and I would answer -3 to "what is the difference of 11 - 14 ?" So I need some details of what output you want, in contrast to the output you get. With examples of both for some sample input.

Answer (score 4):

If you're only after the difference between the two numbers, why not use abs(num1 - num2)?
Then you wouldn't have to care about the order.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cmath/abs/

Comment: well the reason i wanted it to subtract the smaller one from the larger one is so that the answer would not come out as a negative number.

Comment: it won't come out negative after using abs() :P

Answer (score 2):

It seems very straightforward.

```
if (num1 < num2)
   correctAnswer = num2 - num1;
else
   correctAnswer = num1 - num2;
```

Answer (score 1):

just put the logic into a function, and do a simple bool check to decide which result to return.

```
int SubstractSmallerNumber(int num1, int num2){
    if(num1 < num2) return num2 - num1;
    else return num1 - num2;
}
```

This is a brute force method, and you can find smarter ways to solve the problem.
Think about Absolute Value.  If you take the absolute value of the subtraction, you will get the same net effect.

Comment: well i thank you all for the answers, they helped tremendously.